# Ext of an $\mathfrak{m}$-primary ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, homological-algebra

Let $(A,\mathfrak m,k)$ be a Noetherian local ring, $M$ a finitely generated $A$-module, and $I$ an $\mathfrak{m}$-primary ideal. If $\operatorname{Ext}^{i}_{A}(A/\mathfrak{m},M)=0$ then $\operatorname{Ext}^{i}_{A}(A/I,M)=0$?

Comment: I see that you know some LaTeX. Next time, please remember the `$` signs around the LaTeX code. I added them for you this time. (Plus I fixed the mis-spelling of Noetherian. If there really is something called netherian rings, my apologies.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We will use the following result found as Lemma 3.1.11 on page 93 of *Cohen-Macaulay Rings* by Bruns and Herzog. It says: Let $R$ be a Noetherian ring, $M$ an $R$-module, $N$ a finite $R$-module and $n>0$ an integer. Suppose that $\operatorname{Ext}_R^n(R/P, M)=0$ for all $P\in \operatorname{Supp} N$. Then $\operatorname{Ext}_R^n(N,M)=0.$

Going back to the probem at hand, take $N=A/I$. Since $I$ is $\mathfrak m$-primary, $\operatorname{Supp}N=\{\mathfrak m\}$. Now the conclusion follows by the above mentioned result.

Comment: This answer shows that the condition "finitely generated" is superflous for $M$.