# Theorem on Injective Dimension in Weibel's "An Introduction to Homological Algebra"

Tags: commutative-algebra, homological-algebra, injective-module, local-rings

This fact is stated in Weibel's book without proof:

If $A$ is a finitely generated module over a commutative Noetherian local ring $(R,\mathfrak{m},k)$, then $id(A) \le d$ is equivalent to $\operatorname{Ext}^{n}_{R}(k,A)=0$ for all $n > d$.

I can prove one direction since $id(A) \le d$ is equivalent to $\operatorname{Ext}^{n}_{R}(R/\mathfrak{a},A)=0$ for all $n > d$ for all ideals $\mathfrak{a} \subset R$. 
Could you help me with the other direction?

Comment: Just to clarify, you want help for the other direction ?

Comment: Yes, I mean the other direction.

Comment: Would this question be inappropriate on Mathoverflow?

Comment: I've got an answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/612864/ext-of-an-mathfrakm-primary-ideal.